# Define oh my zsh aliases per folder

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a different name for my heroku remote depending on the project, and I would like to have an alias for each of my projects to push to heroku, is there anyway to define an alias per folder, so that inside my project folder I can define the alias pointing to the right heroku remote?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest using a *function* instead of *aliases*.

```sh
# paths to projects 
#  - must be absolute 
#  - must not contain symlinks
#  - must not end with "/"
# run `pwd -P` in the project root to get the correct value
PROJ_A="/path/to/project/a"
PROJ_B="/path/to/project/b"

pushit () {
    case $(pwd -P) in 
        ( $PROJ_A | $PROJ_A/* )
            # Put command(s) needed to push A here
        ;;
        ( $PROJ_B | $PROJ_B/* ) 
            # Put command(s) needed to push B here
        ;;
        ( * )
            echo "You are not in a project directory"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

**Reasoning:**

While it is possible to modify aliases every time the current working directory is changed by utilizing the `chpwd` hook, you only need to know which command to use when you are actually pushing to heroku. So most of the time the aliases would be modified for nothing.

Using a function, the appropriate decisions can be made when you actually need it. And as all of the logic used in the function would be needed anyway when going the `chpwd` route, so you actually reduce the lines of code needed when using the function directly.

Answer (score 4):

Just activate the [`dotenv` plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/dotenv):

```
plugins+=(dotenv)
ZSH_DOTENV_FILE=.any-name-you-like-for-the-per-directory-alias-file
```

Also consider [direnv](https://direnv.net/), which lets you export environment variables in a per-directory `.envrc`, **and** unset them when you move away (which `dotenv` cannot do). direnv is compatible with all the popular shells. However, it doesn't [currently](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/issues/73) let you define aliases or functions.

You can still combine [Adaephon's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29620781/435004) with direnv, by creating a function (rather than an alias) that decides what to do based on one (or several) environment variables, which are in turn set by direnv.

Both approaches deal with the security aspect by having you manually whitelist directories in which the dot files will be sourced.

Answer (score 1):

I'm over two years late, but for anyone who is looking for a similar solution, I just recently finished up a script that should enable you to do just what you are trying to do. Check it out: [localalias](https://github.com/bbugyi200/localalias).

It allows you to create and use pseudo-aliases and functions that are local to the directory they are defined in. Perhaps the best part is that it accomplishes this without performing any dicey "source" commands. These solutions are easier and faster, but are a big security concern.

Here's a demo:

[image]